# Remove TabPage from TabControl

Tags: c#, .net, tabs, tabpage

So i need to dynamically add and delete some `TabPage`. User clicked "Show Tab" = `storage_page`added.

```
private void storage_menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    storage_page.Text = storage_page.Name = "Storage";
    main_tabControl.TabPages.Add(storage_page);
    main_tabControl.SelectedTab = storage_page;
}
```

And the when he chooses another page the `storage_page` has to be removed

```
private void main_tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < main_tabControl.TabPages.Count; i++) {
        if (main_tabControl.TabPages[i].Name.Equals("storage", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && main_tabControl.SelectedTab.Name != "Storage") {
            main_tabControl.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
   }
}
```

When i click "Show Tab" page shows up. But when i select other page i see the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` leading to `Application.Run(new Form_Authentication());` line

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you increase i variable by 1 from 0 to main_tabControl.TabPages.Count

I assume that main_tabControl.TabPages.Count = 10, what is happended if you're removing 7th element? At that time, main_tabControl.TabPages.Count = 4 and i variable = 6. So, i variable is exceed the range of TabPages.

You should to change your code:

```
private void main_tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int i = main_tabControl.TabPages.Count - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        if (main_tabControl.TabPages[i].Name.Equals("storage", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && main_tabControl.SelectedTab.Name != "Storage") {
            main_tabControl.TabPages[i].Dispose();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```